# Django Reverse Match Error with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and programming in general.  I'm going through the book Django For Beginners and have added my own flair in the forms section but have run into a problem.  Below I have detailed the error and provided my code.
**ERROR**
NoReverseMatch at /drug/12/
Reverse for 'drug_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['drug/(?P[0-9]+)/edit/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/drug/12/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'drug_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['drug/(?P[0-9]+)/edit/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\scott\django_sites\history_cloud1\history1_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\scott\django_sites\history_cloud1\history1_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
class DrugInfo(models.Model):
    drug_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='Enter Patient Name',)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.drug_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('drug_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    drugListView, 
    drugDetailView, 
    drugCreateView,
    drugDeleteView,
    drugUpdateView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('drug/<int:pk>/delete/',
        drugDeleteView.as_view(), name='drug_delete'),
    path('drug/new/', drugCreateView.as_view(), name='drug_new'),
    path('drug/<int:pk>/', drugDetailView.as_view(), name='drug_detail'),
    path('drug/<int:pk>/edit/',
        drugUpdateView.as_view(), name='drug_edit'),
    path('', drugListView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import (
    CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
)
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import DrugInfo

class drugListView(ListView):
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'home.html'

class drugDetailView(DetailView):
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'drug_detail.html'
    
class drugCreateView(CreateView):
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'drug_new.html'
    fields = ['drug_name', 'patient_name', 'author']

class drugUpdateView(UpdateView): # new
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'drug_edit.html'
    fields = ['drug_name', 'patient_name']

class drugDeleteView(DeleteView): # new
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'drug_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

**drug_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit Drug Information</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Script Tracker Title Base HTML</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <header>
                <div class="nav-left">
                    <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Script Tracker</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-right">
                    <a href="{% url 'drug_new' %}">+ Add New Drug</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**drug_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="drug-entry">
        <h2>{{ post.drug_name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ post.patient_name }}</h2>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'drug_edit' drug.pk %}">+ Edit Drug Information</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'drug_delete' drug.pk %}">+ Delete Drug</a></p>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Summary**
I'm very new to all this and so I apologize if I have not posted all the needed information.  I know I'm close and I have something messed up with the pk stuff.  http://127.0.0.1:8000/drug/12/edit/ works fine when I type in the browser.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `def` in  `views.py` need an argument `pk`. For example: `def project_update(request, pk_project):...`

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên,  So sorry but I'm not sure what you mean or exactly how to add the above to my views.py.  Could you paste a sample views.py for me?

Comment: I mean if we want update or delete, we need a pk to find object. You can see example here, this is my views.py: https://ideone.com/wJmeaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template `drug_detail.html` you refer to the `DrugInfo` object as follows: `post` or `drug`. While in fact the `drugDetailView` never passes such variables into the context. A `DetailView` by default passes the instance as `object` or `<lowercase_model_name>` (`druginfo` here). If you want to set the name it uses you can set `context_object_name` on the class:

```
class drugDetailView(DetailView):
    model = DrugInfo
    template_name = 'drug_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'drug'
```

Now in the template `drug_detail.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="drug-entry">
        <!-- Use `drug` instead of `post` now -->
        <h2>{{ drug.drug_name }}</h2>
        <h2>{{ drug.patient_name }}</h2>
    </div>

    <p><a href="{% url 'drug_edit' drug.pk %}">+ Edit Drug Information</a></p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'drug_delete' drug.pk %}">+ Delete Drug</a></p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: @smink if you left the view the same it the href of the anchors should be like `{% url 'drug_edit' druginfo.pk %}` or `{% url 'drug_edit' object.pk %}`, etc. (similar for `drug_delete`)

Comment: Thanks so much.  After a little fiddling I figured it out and your above suggestion worked great.  I just left views.py the way it was and replaced drug with druginfo.drug_name/patient_name and then replaced drug.pk with druginfo.pk...  Thanks again so much for your help with this.  I'm learning!!!!  :)